# How to pull excel data into a list to use python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list

I have a program that works perfectly in placing orders for my company for a list that I define. I want to know how I could pull the list from an excel file instead of manually typing them out each time?

code below:

```
Order_List = ['0043777770','003897270','0048377270']

for eachId in Order_List:
#go to website
#find and select item
# enter quantiy
#check out
#save invoice
```

But instead of me manually entering each order# into the order_list can I pull it from an excel file or read through each order # in the excel?
the excel file looks something like this and I need the first column data A2-A20 etc.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading the excel file into pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want, you can also read only the first column with `pd.read_excel`. I think this might be a bit more efficient than reading the whole file.

As I see it, you don't want repeated orders, that's why you can use `set()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A")
# get the first column of df
Order_List  = set(df.iloc[:, 0])

print(Order_List)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.

With for.

Example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('namexlsx.xlsx')
List_order = []
for i in namexlsx.index:
   order = df.at[i, 'Order number']
   List_order.append(order)
```

Comment: There is really no need to loop through df, it is not very efficient. If you really need a list, the df has a method for that, namely `df['Order number'].tolist()`.